# How to store the age of the person using his DOB entered but it's not working

Tags: javascript, php, sql, datetime, sql-insert

Here the DOB has the value of input text field

```
 $DOB = $_POST['DOB'];
 $today = date("d-m-Y");
 $diff = date_diff(date_create($DOB), date_create($today));
 echo 'Age is '.$diff->format('%y');
 $a = $diff->format('%y');
 $age = $_POST[$a];
```

Here is the insert query

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO details (`id`, `email`, `member_id`, `name`, `DOB`, `gender`, 'age')
       VALUES (NULL,'$email2', '$member_id', '$name', '$DOB',  '$gender', '$age')";
 $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

I think it's problem of static I guess it needs to be done dynamically using input text value? How can I get input text value so I can store the age from date of birth entered in DOB field?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend storing the age in the database. This is a derived information, whose value changes over time. Within 1 year after you store it, it will become obsolete.

You can easily compute the age directly in your queries using simple date functions, which are available in most databases (assuming, of course, that you are storing `dob` as a legitimate `date` datatype). Assuming that you are running MySQL:

```
timestampdiff(year, dob, current_date) as age
```

If you are going to type this frequently, you might consider creating a view:

```
create view v_details as
select d.*, timestampdiff(year, dob, current_date) as age
from details d
```